# Auto Close Ant Design TimePicker after choosing time

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd, timepicker

The Ant Design [TimePicker](https://ant.design/components/time-picker/) by default only closes when clicking outside the time selector.

I have a 12 Hour `TimePicker` which is set by default at 12:00 am, how can I have it close automatically when a user selects the hour, minute and am/pm so the user should not have to click outside the TimePicker to close it manually?

```
<TimePicker format="h:mm a" use12Hours defaultOpenValue={moment('24:00', 'h:mm a')} />
```

Comment: What if the user selects am/pm first? Do you still want your timepicker to close?

Comment: Maybe add an "Done" button at the bottom of the opened panel, so that users can click it when done, instead of clicking outside the time selector.

Comment: @ShivamGupta My point is that it should close automatically to improve the UX without having the user close it manually

Comment: @martinschwartz what happens when the user clicks on the am/pm first? 
Then it'll be bad UX

Comment: @ShivamGupta When a user Selects hour AND selects minute AND selects am/pm it should close

Comment: I am not getting footer in Timepicker.. anybody knows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `open` attribute from `TimePicker` component and use a state value to show/hide the timepicker. So everytime the user clicks on time change you can use `onChange` property to change the state value to false

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
<TimePicker
 ...
 open={open}
 onOpenChange={() => {setOpen(true)}})
 onChange={() => {setOpen(false)}}
></TimePicker>
```

Comment: How would I know if the user has already selected the hour, minute & am/pm?

Comment: i am not getting footer in Timpicker.. anybody has solution?

Comment: Try to use `renderExtraFooter` attribute